# Github pages deployement errors

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

Well the page is blank and show me those errors, I think its a problem of paths but i tried too many times
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeTZl.png)
And here is my index.html in dist: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpJ7V.png)

Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.
FaresLoukil/:3 The Content-Security-Policy directive name 'interest-cohort=()' contains one or more invalid characters. Only ASCII alphanumeric characters or dashes '-' are allowed in directive names.
FaresLoukil/:8

```
   GET https://faresloukil.github.io/src/app/app.component.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

FaresLoukil/:14

```
   GET https://faresloukil.github.io/runtime.6101bdd0cb26f292.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

FaresLoukil/:14

```
   GET https://faresloukil.github.io/polyfills.c35bc43da617ab3e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

FaresLoukil/:14

```
   GET https://faresloukil.github.io/main.8562969f8cc6872d.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

FaresLoukil/:11

```
   GET https://faresloukil.github.io/styles.70f4872d6e60b783.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I was expecting to show me only page that i did in my app component.